# Android floating button and advanced webiew do not work

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, webview

I have a floating button with the android advanced web view, everything displays nicely but when I click the floating button it registers the click in the webview and changes page. Its like I am clicking through the webview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.seekadventure.seekadventure.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
        android:id="@+id/newWeb"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

    </im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make your **`FloatingActionButton`**

```
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />
```

Comment: Awesome that was it thanks! Now I just need to figure out the onClick listener!

Comment: Sorry about that, thought i did!